# Publisher is not listed when using the '@article' entry type

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

The publisher is not listed when using the `@article` entry type, the `natbib` citation management package, and the `plainnat` bibliography style. How do I resolve this?

Here is an MWE. Note that "Elsevier" is not included in the typeset bibliographic entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{woodford1990optimum,
  title={The optimum quantity of money},
  author={Woodford, Michael},
  journal={Handbook of monetary economics},
  volume={2},
  pages={1067--1152},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{woodford1990optimum}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal document! This is quite normal for most (all?) bibliography styles I know. Publisher information is used for books (single author and edited volumes) but not for journals.  Do you have a specific style guide that requires it for journals?

Comment: Alan, thanks!  Well, the "Handbook" is a book, so I would usually assume that it is good to list the publisher for anyone who wishes to find it.  Is there a style file that does that?

Comment: @AlanMunn - The main issue is that the OP was using an inappropriate entry type: The "Handbook of Monetary Economics" is not a journal. The real solution is to switch to the `@incollection` entry type.

Comment: @mico This is why we need a broad range of academic specialists on the site! Not every problem is purely a TeXnical one.

Answer (score 3):

It's a **mistake** to use the entry type `@article` for the entry at hand. The `@article` entry should only ever be used for pieces published in scholarly journals. That is decidedly not the case here: The "Handbook of Monetary Economics" is not, and has never been, a journal.

So, what to do? You really should be using the `@incollection` entry type. Changing the entry type to `@incollection`, changing the `journal` field to `booktitle`, and back-filling some missing fields (such as `editor`, `chapter`, and `address`), one gets:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@incollection{woodford1990optimum,
  title     = {The optimum quantity of money},
  author    = {Woodford, Michael},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Monetary Economics, Volume~2},
  editor    = {Benjamin M. Friedman and Frank H. Hahn},
  chapter   = 20,
  pages     = {1067--1152},
  year      = {1990},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  address   = {Amsterdam},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % optional
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % or, if desired, use 'numbers' option
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```